# groovy script to update existing jenkins jobs with slack notification

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to update existing jenkins jobs with slack notification plugin.

Been stuck on this for a long time, can someone please guide me? Appreciate your help guys.

tried the following in jenkins script console:

```
for (item in Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("TestJob")) {
  item.publishersList.replace(new jenkins.plugins.slack.SlackNotifier('http://example.com', 'chann', 'jkkljh7777kkjlkj', false, '', '', '', true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, null, true, 'hmm'))
}
```

getting the following error.

> groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: jenkins.plugins.slack.SlackNotifier(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, null, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.String)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1731)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1534)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.MetaClassConstructorSite.callConstructor(MetaClassConstructorSite.java:49)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
>       at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:2)
>       at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:585)
>       at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:623)
>       at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:594)
>       at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:142)
>       at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:114)
>       at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
>       at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics.executeGroovy(RemotingDiagnostics.java:111)
>       at jenkins.model.Jenkins._doScript(Jenkins.java:4295)
>       at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doScript(Jenkins.java:4267)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:335)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:175)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:108)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:124)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:135)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.corsfilter.AccessControlsFilter.doFilter(AccessControlsFilter.java:79)
>       at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
>       at com.smartcodeltd.jenkinsci.plugin.assetbundler.filters.LessCSS.doFilter(LessCSS.java:47)
>       at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
>       at hudson.plugins.greenballs.GreenBallFilter.doFilter(GreenBallFilter.java:59)
>       at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
>       at hudson.plugins.audit_trail.AuditTrailFilter.doFilter(AuditTrailFilter.java:95)
>       at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
>       at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:126)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:80)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
>       at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
>       at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>       at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
>       at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:558)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:299)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Slack Notification Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/slack) and post to Slack like this:

`stage('notify') {
  withCredentials([[$class: 'StringBinding', credentialsId: 'my-id', variable: 'my-slack-token']]) {
    slackSend(message: "my status message", teamDomain: 'my-team', token: env.my-slack-token, channel: '#my-channel', color: 'good')
  }
}`

Please keep in mind that you'll need to create credentials for your Slack integration token (I'm calling that my-credentials-id and then giving that value to the variable my-slack-token). You can create that credential in "Manage Jenkins" > "Credentials".

Sorry for formatting. :(

Comment: Thanks Jacob. But you use this while creating a job. I plan on editing an exisiting job and I dont have the dsl of it. it was created with jenkins gui. Now I am curious on creating a job which can edit any existing job by adding a slack notification to it using groovy. :)

Comment: @SubhenduChatterjee Have you found any way to update Jenkins job slack notification channel name via groovy script?